# Any way to prevent Doctrine result to nest entities when adding custom field to QueryBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am adding a calculated field named 'distance' to a Doctrine query but the result is then nesting the entities as follow:

```
[
   {
      "0": {
         "name": "Some name",
         "id": 3
      },
      "distance": "10"
   },
   {
     ...
]
```

Is there a way to tell Doctrine to format the response like this instead?

```
[
   {
      "name": "Some name",
      "id": 3
      "distance": "10"  
   },
   {
     ...
]
```

I don't always add this field as it depends of the search criteria, so I am having inconsistent result format.

Also I can prevent the issue by adding the distance field as HIDDEN, but then I lose the distance information, which I would like to keep.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you can set hydration mode to array

Comment: @Eakethet I see thanks. Unfortunately I can't change the hydrate mode that easily, because this part is handed over to the framework I am using (api plateform)

Comment: Ehm, so you can just modify the query?

Comment: In current state, yes, the queryBuilder and the Entity.

Comment: So you can do $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult(); or not?

Comment: no because I only have access to the querybuilder via a filter function. This function is not responsible for getting the results.

Comment: well, you will need to rebuild it by your own, eg. https://3v4l.org/lJaEG

Comment: I am surprise Doctrine don't have out of the box solution to hydrate non persistent field to entity, but I think you are right, that the only way to deal with it. thanks!

Comment: I'm not, entity should be something stale, so you know what you can expect. If there would be additional optionable field, how would you handle this? Consider `public function doSomething(YourEntity $e){ $e->distance;); 1) your IDE will shout about undefined property, 2) if you pass entity from eg. manager and not from that api, there will be undefined property, so IMHO it is much more consistent the way it is.

Comment: I think it's fine if entity is different based on the api call. The client knows what to expect in this specific context. So the client will only call doSomething in this context. To answer how technically Doctrine could do that, I think it could have either an annotation set on a none persistent attribute for the entity, like 'if distance is in the result fields, assign it', or at the query builder, a query token like ->select('(something) as ASSIGN position') that would tell Doctrine to add the position property the the entity.

Comment: And IMHO I don't think IDE should dictate how to code!